# Cloned select with 'change' event stops updating

Tags: jquery

I am cloning a select dropdown and populating it with new options:

```
var oldSelect = $("select[name='old']")
var newSelect = oldSelect.clone(true);
newSelect.html(newoptions);
oldSelect.replaceWith(newSelect);
```

This brings along a change event that was bound earlier:

```
$("select[name='old']").bind('change', function(){ update(); });
```

My new select works, and the update event fires correctly, but the option that the user selects does not appear in the box (see attached image).

[image: Select box not displaying value on change]

Comment: Are you re-binding after the clone?

Comment: Using .clone(true) attaches the bound events to the new object; but I did try binding after replace and the effect is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the update function that was executed on change was redrawing the select box, which reset the selected option back to null. It happened so quickly that I didn't notice the replacement.